# Count comparison where some characters are numeric

Tags: sql

Using you guys as a sounding board really, but here is my situation

I am trying to figure out how to create an accurate count for an employee table, based off of employee number (Num field) where some employee numbers have letters in them.

Details:
Four companies, merged about 2 years ago. Main company has always used pure numbers for the Employee number. First Sub Company used to use letters and numbers, now have switched to all Numbers, but older employee records still have letters. (The other sub companies are in the same table, but for purposes of this report they do not matter)

All employee records from 00000-55555 are main company and 55556-88888 First Sub company. Also, any employee numbers with Letters in them are also part of the First Sub Company.

I know how to make a case statement purely for the number ranges, but the Letter portions of the Employee number are throwing me off.

I'm not sure how to create an accurate count of the employee numbersfor the two companies. with those being present as well

Comment: Where are the non-numeric employee numbers being stored, if eomployee nubmer is a numeric field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (if my understanding of your situation is correc):

```
SELECT
    SUM( IsFirstSubCompany ) FirstSubCompanyEmployeeCount
    , SUM( IsMainCompany ) MainCompanyEmployeeCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IsFirstSubCompany = CASE 
                WHEN u.Num LIKE '%[a-z]%' OR ( 1 = ISNUMERIC( u.Num ) AND CONVERT( INT, u.Num ) BETWEEN 55556 AND 88888 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END,
            IsMainCompany = CASE
                WHEN 1 = ISNUMERIC( u.Num ) AND CONVERT( int, u.Num ) BETWEEN 00000 and 55555 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END
        FROM
            UserTable u    
    ) q
```

Comment: I marked the answer but am unable to upvote. I do not have enough reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SQL Server (you don't mentioned your RDBMS in your post), you can use the following to achieve what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  Company,
        COUNT(*) AS NoOfEmployees
FROM
    (
        SELECT  CASE ISNUMERIC(EmployeeNo)
                    WHEN 1 THEN
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (EmployeeNo < 55556) THEN 'Main Company'
                            ELSE 'First Sub Company'
                        END
                    ELSE 'First Sub Company'
                END AS Company
          FROM  [table]
    ) a
GROUP BY Company
```

Remember to replace `EmployeeNo` with the actual name of your employee number column, and `table` with the name of your table.

This will output a table containing a Company column (First Sub Company or Main Company) followed by the number of employees that belong to each.

Comment: Basically, I'd probably choose this method. I can see two issues in this particular query, though. #1) The ISNUMERIC test method is unreliable in general and may give false positives for this particular problem. For instance, `1E1` would yield `true`. I'd probably use `LIKE '%[a-z]%'` or perhaps `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` instead. #2) You probably need to stipulate that if the number is not less than 55556, it still should not exceed 88888 to qualify as the First Sub Company's one. (I.e. a simple ELSE may not be enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQLServer, try:

```
with cte as
(select
 case when convert(numeric,
                   case isnumeric(employee_no) when 1 then employee_no else '99999' end)
           between 0 and 55555 then 'Main' else 'Sub' end co
 from employee)
select co, count(*) from cte group by co
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21f36/7))